# Interactive Confusion Matrix for Data Visualization

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization, data-visualization, confusion-matrix

I have plotted a ROC Curve using a scatter plot from Google developers. The code is [image]

and the output is

[image]

I want to make it interactive by showing a confusion matrix when a user clicks on the points in the scatter plot (All the points have a corresponding confusion matrix).

I found this :https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#overview

but here the pie chart changes as per whatever the variable is but I want the table contents to be updated as soon as a user clicks on the data point.

Sample of table can be:

[image]

I want to know how can we relate the data points of the scatter plot to the table data of table.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Working on a plunk of this problem... in future, code formatted as text instead of an image is more convenient for writing demos.

Comment: I will take care of this. @Balrog30 Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a custom tooltip and render your confusion matrices in a column of the DataTable.

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_tooltip_content

Here's an [interactive demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/DvyK7qpk8UxRE7UsdKLR) with something like what you might like.  Note that after converting the array to a data table I add role and html properties to the tooltip column.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("visualization", "1", {
      packages: ["corechart"]
    });
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['FPR', 'TPR', 'Tooltip'],
        [0.934911, 0.98659,
          '<table><tr><td>n=165</td><th>Predicted:<br/>NO</th><th>Predicted:<br/>YES</th></tr><tr><th>Actual:<br/>NO</th><td>TN = 50</td><td>FP = 10</td></tr><th>Actual:<br/>YES</th><td>FN = 5</td><td>TP = 100</td></tr></table></div>'],
        [0.852071, 0.978927, 
          '<table><tr><td>n=165</td><th>Predicted:<br/>NO</th><th>Predicted:<br/>YES</th></tr><tr><th>Actual:<br/>NO</th><td>TN = 50</td><td>FP = 10</td></tr><th>Actual:<br/>YES</th><td>FN = 5</td><td>TP = 100</td></tr></table></div>'],
        [0.715976, 0.94636,
          '<table><tr><td>n=165</td><th>Predicted:<br/>NO</th><th>Predicted:<br/>YES</th></tr><tr><th>Actual:<br/>NO</th><td>TN = 50</td><td>FP = 10</td></tr><th>Actual:<br/>YES</th><td>FN = 5</td><td>TP = 100</td></tr></table></div>'],
        [0.594675, 0.925287, 
          '<table><tr><td>n=165</td><th>Predicted:<br/>NO</th><th>Predicted:<br/>YES</th></tr><tr><th>Actual:<br/>NO</th><td>TN = 50</td><td>FP = 10</td></tr><th>Actual:<br/>YES</th><td>FN = 5</td><td>TP = 100</td></tr></table></div>'],
        [0.402367, 0.812261, 
          '<table><tr><td>n=165</td><th>Predicted:<br/>NO</th><th>Predicted:<br/>YES</th></tr><tr><th>Actual:<br/>NO</th><td>TN = 50</td><td>FP = 10</td></tr><th>Actual:<br/>YES</th><td>FN = 5</td><td>TP = 100</td></tr></table></div>'],
        [0.186391, 0.695402, 
          '<table><tr><td>n=165</td><th>Predicted:<br/>NO</th><th>Predicted:<br/>YES</th></tr><tr><th>Actual:<br/>NO</th><td>TN = 50</td><td>FP = 10</td></tr><th>Actual:<br/>YES</th><td>FN = 5</td><td>TP = 100</td></tr></table></div>'],
        [0.12426, 0.564134,
          '<table><tr><td>n=165</td><th>Predicted:<br/>NO</th><th>Predicted:<br/>YES</th></tr><tr><th>Actual:<br/>NO</th><td>TN = 50</td><td>FP = 10</td></tr><th>Actual:<br/>YES</th><td>FN = 5</td><td>TP = 100</td></tr></table></div>'],
        [0.056123, 0.390805, 
          '<table><tr><td>n=165</td><th>Predicted:<br/>NO</th><th>Predicted:<br/>YES</th></tr><tr><th>Actual:<br/>NO</th><td>TN = 50</td><td>FP = 10</td></tr><th>Actual:<br/>YES</th><td>FN = 5</td><td>TP = 100</td></tr></table></div>'],
        [0.029586, 0.247126, 
          '<table><tr><td>n=165</td><th>Predicted:<br/>NO</th><th>Predicted:<br/>YES</th></tr><tr><th>Actual:<br/>NO</th><td>TN = 50</td><td>FP = 10</td></tr><th>Actual:<br/>YES</th><td>FN = 5</td><td>TP = 100</td></tr></table></div>'],
        [0.011834, 0.074713, 
          '<table><tr><td>n=165</td><th>Predicted:<br/>NO</th><th>Predicted:<br/>YES</th></tr><tr><th>Actual:<br/>NO</th><td>TN = 50</td><td>FP = 10</td></tr><th>Actual:<br/>YES</th><td>FN = 5</td><td>TP = 100</td></tr></table></div>']
      ]);

      data.setColumnProperty(2, 'role', 'tooltip');
      data.setColumnProperty(2, 'html', true);
      var options = {
        title: 'ROC Curve',
        hAxis: {
          title: 'False Positive Rate',
          minValue: 0,
          maxValue: 1
        },
        vAxis: {
          title: 'True Positive Rate',
          minValue: 0,
          maxValue: 1
        },
        legend: 'none',
        tooltip: {
          isHtml: true
        }
      };
      var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="chart_div" style="width:900px;height:500px;"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is there a way to get a separate table in the body of html instead of when I hover over it

Comment: Instead of using the tooltip you could use the select event and then populate the table using the selection from `chart.getSelection();`. [Select Event Docs](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/events#the-select-event)  You could also try to mess with the styles rules on the `<div>` tag that the tooltip is rendered into.  I'm not sure the second idea would work, though because the rules are assigned to the element directly, so using style sheets wouldn't override the more specific element styles.

Comment: I’m always happy to see an answer keep on giving.